# Mysql changes listener for node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

Is there a way that mysql server in node.js listens for changes in the database and get a callback for that changes like Database Changes Notification in Oracle DB?

I'm thinking to implement it somewhat like this way

```
var mongo = require("mysql"); 
var client = require('socket.io').listen(port).sockets;
var db = mysql.createConnection({host: host, user: user, database: db});

db.listen.on('changes',function(){
   client.emit("hasChanges");
});
```

Comment: did you find any answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

You can try, the [mysql-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events) package for NodeJS.
But before you try:

> Make sure the database user has the privilege to read the binlog on database that you want to watch on.

Comment: Do you know if this package can still be used? I just need to listen for updates!